# Call to a member function links() on array

Tags: php, laravel, pagination, laravel-livewire

I´m using Laravel 8 with Livewire.

I have create this to show a list of items and the user can apply filters as well. Upon load the data gets shown, 10 records per page.
However when I try to click next page or a specific page number I get the error "Call to a member function links() on array..."

I´m also using repository and it´s injected on the livewire component.

```
use App\Models\Repositories\Interfaces\LojaAdesaoRepositoryInterface;
use Livewire\Component;
use Livewire\WithPagination;

This is my component

class Adesao extends Component
{
    use WithPagination;

    protected $repository;    
    public $cnpj;
    public $razaoSocial;
    public $nomeFantasia;
    public $regulamentacaoId;
    public $regiaoId;
    public $faturamentoId;
    private $filtros = [
        "cnpj" => "",
        "razao_social" => "",
        "nome_fantasia" =>  "",
        //"regulamentacao_id" =>  "",
        //"regiao_id" =>  "",
        //"faturamento_id" =>  ""
    ];

    private $lojas = [];
    
    protected $listeners = ['regiaoMudanca' => 'regiaoMudanca', 'faturamentoListener' => 'faturamentoListener', 'regulamentacaoListener' => 'regulamentacaoListener'];

    public function mount(LojaAdesaoRepositoryInterface $respository)
    {
        
        $this->repository = $respository;
        $lojas = $this->retornaListaInicial();
        $this->setLojas($lojas);
    }

    public function render(LojaAdesaoRepositoryInterface $respository)
    {   
        $this->repository = $respository;
        $lojas = $this->getLojas();
        
        return view('livewire.lojas.adesao',['lojasAdesao' => $lojas]);
    }

    public function regiaoMudanca($value){
        $this->filtros['regiao_id'] = $value;
    }

    public function faturamentoListener($value){
        $this->filtros['faturamento_id'] = $value;
    }

    public function regulamentacaoListener($value){
        
        $this->filtros['regulamentacao_id'] = $value;
    }

    public function submitForm(LojaAdesaoRepositoryInterface $respository){
        
        $this->resetPage();
        $this->repository = $respository;
        $this->filtros["cnpj"] = $this->cnpj;
        $this->filtros["razao_social"] = $this->razaoSocial;
        $this->filtros["nome_fantasia"] =  $this->nomeFantasia;
        
        $lojas = $this->repository->filterBy($this->filtros);
        $this->setLojas($lojas);
        
    }

    private function retornaListaInicial(){
        return $this->repository->filterBy([]);
    }

    private function setLojas($lojas){
        //dd($lojas->links());
        $this->lojas = $lojas;
    }

    private function getLojas(){
        return $this->lojas;
    }
}
```

```
<div>
<x-nav-bar.nav/>
<form wire:submit.prevent="submitForm()" method="get">
<div class="container mx-auto px-4 sm:px-8">
    <div class="flex justify-center pt-8 sm:justify-start sm:pt-0 text-gray-900 dark:text-white">
    LOJA ADESÃO
    </div>
    
        <div class="grid grid-cols-1 md:grid-cols-3 border-t border-b border-gray-200 dark:border-gray-700">
            
            <div class="p-3">
                <div class="flex items-center">
                    <label class="block font-semibold text-gray-900 dark:text-white">CNPJ<label>
                    <input type="text" wire:model.defer="cnpj" maxlength="15" placeholder="CNPJ" name="cnpj" id="cnpj" class="w-full h-4 px-3 py-5 mt-2 hover:outline-none focus:outline-none border-none focus:ring-1 bg-white text-sm dark:bg-gray-800  rounded-md">
                    
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="p-3">
                <div class="flex items-center">
                    <label class="block font-semibold text-gray-900 dark:text-white">Razão Social<label>
                    <input type="text" wire:model.defer="razaoSocial" maxlength="60" placeholder="Razão Social" name="razaoSocial" id="razaoSocial" class="w-full h-4 px-3 py-5 mt-2 hover:outline-none focus:outline-none border-none focus:ring-1 bg-white text-sm dark:bg-gray-800 rounded-md">                
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="p-3">
                <div class="flex items-center">
                    <label class="block font-semibold text-gray-900 dark:text-white">Nome Fantasia<label>
                    <input type="text" maxlength="60" wire:model.defer="nomeFantasia" placeholder="Nome Fantasia" name="nomeFantasia" id="nomeFantasia" class="w-full h-4 px-3 py-5 mt-2 hover:outline-none focus:outline-none border-none focus:ring-1 bg-white text-sm dark:bg-gray-800 rounded-md">
                </div>
            </div>
        
            <div class="p-3">
                <div class="flex items-center">
                    <label class="block font-semibold text-gray-900 dark:text-white">Regulamentação<label>
                    <livewire:dropdown-list.regulamentacao />
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="p-3">
                <div class="flex items-center">
                    <label class="block font-semibold text-gray-900 dark:text-white">Faturamento<label>
                    <livewire:dropdown-list.faturamento />
                </div>
            </div>
            
            <div class="p-3">
                <div class="flex items-center">
                    <label class="block font-semibold text-gray-900 dark:text-white">Região<label>
                    <livewire:dropdown-list.regiao />
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="p-3 col-start-3">                
                <button type="submit" class="text-gray-700 py-2 px-6 rounded-lg dark:text-gray-200 hover:bg-gray-300 dark:hover:bg-gray-700 focus:outline-none">Aplicar Filtro</button>
                <button type="reset" class="text-gray-700 py-2 px-6 rounded-lg dark:text-gray-200 hover:bg-gray-300 dark:hover:bg-gray-700 focus:outline-none">Limpar Filtros</button>
            </div>        
        </div>
    
</div>
</form>
<div class="container mx-auto px-4 sm:px-8">
    <div class="py-8">
        <div class="-mx-4 sm:-mx-8 px-4 sm:px-8 py-4 overflow-x-auto">
        <div class="inline-block min-w-full shadow-md rounded-lg overflow-hidden">
            <table class="min-w-full leading-normal border border-gray-200">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th class="px-5 py-3 border-b-2 border-gray-200 bg-gray-500 text-left text-xs font-semibold text-gray-700 uppercase tracking-wider">
                            <input type="checkbox" name="all" id="all" class="rounded  appearance-none checked:bg-blue-600 checked:border-transparent">
                        </th>
                        <th class="px-5 py-3 border-b-2 border-gray-200 bg-gray-500 text-white text-left text-xs font-semibold uppercase tracking-wider">
                            CNPJ
                        </th>
                        <th class="px-5 py-3 border-b-2 border-gray-200 bg-gray-500 text-white text-left text-xs font-semibold uppercase tracking-wider">
                            Razão Social
                        </th>
                        <th class="px-5 py-3 border-b-2 border-gray-200 bg-gray-500 text-white text-left text-xs font-semibold uppercase tracking-wider">
                            Nome Fantasia
                        </th>
                        <th class="px-5 py-3 border-b-2 border-gray-200 bg-gray-500 text-white text-left text-xs font-semibold uppercase tracking-wider">
                            Regulamentação
                        </th>
                        <th class="px-5 py-3 border-b-2 border-gray-200 bg-gray-500 text-white text-left text-xs font-semibold uppercase tracking-wider">
                            Região
                        </th>
                        <th class="px-5 py-3 border-b-2 border-gray-200 bg-gray-500 text-white text-left text-xs font-semibold uppercase tracking-wider">
                            Faturamento
                        </th>
                        <th class="px-5 py-3 border-b-2 border-gray-200 bg-gray-500 text-white text-center text-xs font-semibold uppercase tracking-wider">
                            Ação
                        </th>                        
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    @foreach ($lojasAdesao as $lojaAdesao)
                        <tr class="">
                            <td class="px-5 py-5 border-b border-gray-200 bg-white text-sm  dark:bg-gray-800">
                                <input type="checkbox" class="rounded  appearance-none checked:bg-blue-600 checked:border-transparent">
                            </td>
                            <td class="px-5 py-5 border-b border-gray-200 text-xs dark:bg-gray-800">
                                <p class="text-white whitespace-no-wrap">{{ $lojaAdesao->cnpj }}</p>
                            </td>
                            <td class="px-5 py-5 border-b border-gray-200 bg-white text-xs dark:bg-gray-800">
                                <p class="text-white whitespace-no-wrap">{{ $lojaAdesao->razao_social }}</p>
                            </td>
                            <td class="px-5 py-5 border-b border-gray-200 bg-white text-xs dark:bg-gray-800">
                                <p class="text-white whitespace-no-wrap">{{ $lojaAdesao->nome_fantasia }}</p>
                            </td>
                            <td class="px-5 py-5 border-b border-gray-200 bg-white text-xs dark:bg-gray-800">
                                <p class="text-white whitespace-no-wrap">{{ $lojaAdesao->regulamentacao->descricao }}</p>
                            </td>
                            <td class="px-5 py-5 border-b border-gray-200 bg-white text-xs dark:bg-gray-800">
                                <p class="text-white whitespace-no-wrap">{{ $lojaAdesao->endereco->estado->regiao[0]['descricao'] }}</p>
                            </td>
                            <td class="px-5 py-5 border-b border-gray-200 bg-white text-xs  dark:bg-gray-800">
                                <p class="text-white whitespace-no-wrap">{{ $lojaAdesao->faturamento->descricao }}</p>
                            </td>
                            <td class="px-5 py-5 border-b border-gray-200 bg-white text-center text-sm dark:bg-gray-800">
                                <button class="text-gray-700 dark:text-gray-200 hover:bg-gray-300 dark:hover:bg-gray-700 px-6 rounded-lg focus:outline-none">Atualizar</button>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    @endforeach
            </tbody>
        </table>        
        </div>
        {{$lojasAdesao->links()}}
    </div>
    </div>
</div>
</div>
<div class="container mx-auto px-4 sm:px-8">
    <div class="grid grid-cols-1 md:grid-cols-4 dark:border-gray-700">
        <div class="p-3">
            <div class="flex items-center">
                <button class="text-gray-700 py-2 px-6 rounded-lg dark:text-gray-200 hover:bg-gray-300 dark:hover:bg-gray-700 focus:outline-none">Selecionar Pesquisador(a)</button>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="p-3">
            <div class="flex items-center">
                <button class="text-gray-700 py-2 px-6 rounded-lg dark:text-gray-200 hover:bg-gray-300 dark:hover:bg-gray-700 focus:outline-none">Importar</button>
            </div>
        </div>
        
    </div>
</div>
</div>
```

```
use App\Models\Repositories\Interfaces\LojaAdesaoRepositoryInterface;
use App\Models\LojaAdesao;
use App\Models\Repositories\Base\BaseRepository;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\HasFactory;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;

use function PHPUnit\Framework\isNull;

class LojaAdesaoRepository extends BaseRepository implements LojaAdesaoRepositoryInterface
{
    use HasFactory;
    protected $model = null;

    /**
    * UserRepository constructor.
    *
    * @param Campos $model
    */
    public function __construct(LojaAdesao $model)
    {
        parent::__construct($model);
        $this->model = $model;
    }

    public function filterBy(array $filtros, int $pageSize=10) {
        DB::enableQueryLog(); 
        $result= $this->model->where(function($q) use ($filtros){
                foreach($filtros as $key => $value)
                {                    
                    if (  $this->ehCampoLike($key) && !empty($value) ){
                        $q->where($key, 'like', '%' . $value . '%');
                    }
                    else{
                        if (!empty($value)  ){
                            $q->where($key,'=', $value);
                        }
                    }
                }
            })->orderBy('cnpj', 'asc')->paginate($pageSize);

            //dd(DB::getQueryLog());
            return $result;
    }

    private function ehCampoLike(string $filtro): bool{
        if ( $filtro == "cnpj" || $filtro == "razao_social" || $filtro == "nome_fantasia"){
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi @Amando, what returns in `dd` inside setLojas method?

Comment: I think I understood you problem, is related Livewire Lifecycle.

Comment: @ViníciusFagundes, the dd returns the pagination navigation. But upon clicking on a page number or < > option, I get the error the titles this issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Short answer**

move this from `mount` to `render` method:

```php
$lojas = $this->retornaListaInicial();
$this->setLojas($lojas);
```

**Explanation**

Notice your both methods `mount` and `render`, while mount is called once on component startup, render is called every server call. So somehow when you change the page, only render is called and `$lojas = $this->getLojas();` returns its initial value, a empty array.

```php
    public function mount(LojaAdesaoRepositoryInterface $respository)
    {
        
        $this->repository = $respository;
        $lojas = $this->retornaListaInicial();
        $this->setLojas($lojas);
    }

    public function render(LojaAdesaoRepositoryInterface $respository)
    {   
        $this->repository = $respository;
        $lojas = $this->getLojas();
        
        return view('livewire.lojas.adesao',['lojasAdesao' => $lojas]);
    }
```

Comment: Thanks Vinicius,
This change resolved the issue. I guess that´s the reason why we should not use private or protected variable to save the state as mention Livewire.

Comment: Nice! Please make sure to mark my answer as the correct, consider if possible vote up! :)